# AWS API Gateway Method Response Correction of Indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I've an issue, with `AWS API Gateway Method Response`, while creating them, I made them `dynamic` so I can add later the extra `responses` if required, but I've noticed that, `resource_id` is not correct.

---

Here is the `resource`

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
   for_each            = { for key, value in flatten(var.responses) : key => value }
   resource_id         = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_resource.nesteds : value.id ], each.key)
   rest_api_id         = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main    : value.id ], each.key)
   http_method         = element([ for key, value in aws_api_gateway_method.nesteds   : value.http_method ], each.key)
   status_code         = lookup(each.value, "code",     null)
   response_models     = lookup(each.value, "models",   null)
   response_parameters = lookup(each.value, "options",  null)
}
```

---

Inputs

```
# 1ST MAIN
responses   = [
   # 202
   {
       code        = 202
       models      = null
       options     = null
       description = "Slim Request accepted 'Ok'"
   },
   # 400
   {
       code        = 400
       models      = null
       options     = null
       description = "Incorrect slim request body 'Error' "
   }
]


# 2ND NESTED
responses   = [
   # 202
   {
       code        = 202
       models      = null
       options     = null
       description = "Stack Request accepted 'Ok'"
   },
   # 400
   {
       code        = 400
       models      = null
       options     = null
       description = "Incorrect stack request body 'Error' "
   }
]
```

---

Terraform Plan/Apply

```
# module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "DELETE"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "fsatfb"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "202"
    }

  # module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "POST"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "s3eg5z"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "400"
    }

  # module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["2"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "DELETE"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "fsatfb"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "202"
    }

  # module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["3"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "POST"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "s3eg5z"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "400"
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

---

I've removed unused elements, from inputs. So issue is with `resource_id` as mentioned already. If you notice I've in total 4 resources that will be created, each of objects are binding with `http_method`. At the end the method `DELETE` must use whole block, but it is using only first object of list, instead of using all. `DELETE` must have `status_code` 202 and 400 but it has only 202 two times, it will not be created, and will throw an error of conflicts, same is applies for `POST` method.

To summarise my problem, how my resource creation look like to achieve this:

```
  # module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "DELETE"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "fsatfb"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "202"
    }

  # module.restapi.aws_api_gateway_method_response.response["1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response" {
      + http_method = "DELETE"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + resource_id = "fsatfb"
      + rest_api_id = "mtu4b34wn4"
      + status_code = "400"
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried with `count` it could behave differently as far as I know

Comment: Hi @BowBow yes I did, the behaviour is same